# How to show a dialog with ok and cancel on button click in wpf (mvvm)?

Tags: wpf, mvvm, showdialog

I am trying to display a dialog with ok and cancel button on a button click. And depending on the dialog result I would like to save\cancel the operation in wpf. I am not sure how to show a dialog in wpf. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [Close View from View Model](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/499977/Closing-View-from-ViewModel)
article form code project

[Showing Dialogs When Using the MVVM Pattern](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36745/Showing-Dialogs-When-Using-the-MVVM-Pattern)

[MVVM and DialogResult](http://blog.excastle.com/2010/07/25/mvvm-and-dialogresult-with-no-code-behind/)

Comment: thanks! But is there any default show dialog box available in WPF?  or we have to create our own dialog?

Comment: Do you require MessageBox, or custom dialog box?

Comment: I think as of now a MessageBox would be enough as I have to confirm the operation by showing a message. If user clicks on cancel then cancel the operation else save the operation.

Comment: [System.Windows.MessageBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms602949.aspx) is WPF Messagebox equivalent. You should wrap messagebox over IMesageBoxService, and in your implementation you should map DialogBoxResult to yes/no etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't use MVVM to do that.
Using the MVVM pattern does **not** mean to *never* use events and codebehind.

In my opinion, the best healthy mix using the MVVM pattern is to use bindings and commands and other "MVVM-stuff" in the XAML, but also events and code. If it has to do with the UI strictly (like a messagebox or double click or thread handling), use code the old-fashion way.

So use the MessageBox.Show("hello"); in the codebehind as usual, because it is UI related and has less meaning to the model/logic.
The same goes with OpenFileDialog and other dialogs.